# Erro Sitaxe consulta PHP no XML

Tags: php

Olá,

Estou procurando uma solução para consultar informações dentro de um XML, econtrei um tutorial na internet, mas o código está com um erro que não consigo resolver.

O código é essE:

```
<?php
# Carrega e armazena o XML na variavel $xml
$xml = simplexml_load_file(“estante.xml”);
# laço dentro da tag livro para cada tag livro que encontrar
foreach($xml->xpath(‘//livro‘) as $livro)
{
    # armazena na var $registro o conteudo de uma tag livro
    $registro = simplexml_load_string($livro->asXML());
    # executa uma consulta XPath e armazena em $busca
$busca = $registro->xpath(‘//preco[.>55.00]‘);
# verificando se houve alguma busca com sucesso
    if($busca){
# exibindo os resultados encontrados
echo $livro->titulo . “<br>”;
echo $livro->descricao . “<br>”;
echo $livro->preco . “<br><br>”;
    }
}
?>
```

O XML que ele consultar é esse:

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”iso-8859-1″?>
<livros>
<livro>
<cod>01</cod>
<titulo>PHP para iniciantes</titulo>
<descricao>Desenvolvendo Aplicações web</descricao>
<autor>Manuel da Silva</autor>
<paginas>200</paginas>
<preco>50.00</preco>
</livro>
<livro>
<cod>02</cod>
<titulo>XML</titulo>
<descricao>Usando XML com PHP </descricao>
<autor>José das Couves</autor>
<paginas>100</paginas>
<preco>150.00</preco>
</livro>
<livro>
<cod>03</cod>
<titulo>Javascript</titulo>
<descricao>O Poder do javascript</descricao>
<autor>Billy Borny</autor>
<paginas>80</paginas>
<preco>90.90</preco>
</livro>
</livros>
```

O erro que eu recebo como retorno é um erro na Linha 6 com essa informação:

```
[19-Feb-2019 15:22:22 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ')' in /home3/smarts43/public_html/app/index.php on line 6
```

Acredito que deva ser um erro simples, se alguém tiver uma luz pra me ajudar, já segui as orientações que ele retorna, mas o erro persiste.

Obrigado,

Comment: Não entendi a finalidade das duas barras na linha do `foreach`? é assim mesmo que está seu código? pq se for, vc está abrindo parentêses, e não está fechando pq o restante da linha está comentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja bem, há 2 pontos no seu código PHP que estão [comentados](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.comments.php).

---

```
...
foreach($xml->xpath(‘//livro‘) as $livro)
{
...
```

E

```
...
$busca = $registro->xpath(‘//preco[.>55.00]‘);
...
```

---

O erro em questão é bastante intuitivo.

> [19-Feb-2019 15:22:22 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected
>   '{', expecting ',' or ')' in /home3/smarts43/public_html/app/index.php
>   on line 6

Você deve atentar-se aos erros pois afinal ele está lhe informando que "esperava" uma `,` (possível outro parâmetro) ou `)` (o fechamento do próprio `foreach`).

No seu caso apenas remova os comentários do código que este erro será sanado.

```
...
foreach($xml->xpath('livro') as $livro)
{
...
$busca = $registro->xpath('preco[.>55.00]');
...
```

---

**EDIT:**

Código funcionando:

PHP

```
<?php

# Carrega e armazena o XML na variavel $xml
$xml = simplexml_load_file("teste.xml");
# laço dentro da tag livro para cada tag livro que encontrar
foreach($xml->xpath('livro') as $livro)
{
    # armazena na var $registro o conteudo de uma tag livro
    $registro = simplexml_load_string($livro->asXML());
    # executa uma consulta XPath e armazena em $busca
    $busca = $registro->xpath("preco[.>55.00]");
    # verificando se houve alguma busca com sucesso

    if($busca){
        # exibindo os resultados encontrados
        echo $livro->titulo . '<br>';
        echo $livro->descricao . '<br>';
        echo $livro->preco . '<br><br>';
    }
}
?>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<livros>
<livro>
<cod>01</cod>
<titulo>PHP para iniciantes</titulo>
<descricao>Desenvolvendo Aplicações web</descricao>
<autor>Manuel da Silva</autor>
<paginas>200</paginas>
<preco>50.00</preco>
</livro>
<livro>
<cod>02</cod>
<titulo>XML</titulo>
<descricao>Usando XML com PHP </descricao>
<autor>José das Couves</autor>
<paginas>100</paginas>
<preco>150.00</preco>
</livro>
<livro>
<cod>03</cod>
<titulo>Javascript</titulo>
<descricao>O Poder do javascript</descricao>
<autor>Billy Borny</autor>
<paginas>80</paginas>
<preco>90.90</preco>
</livro>
</livros>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Fiz o que falou e apareceu outro erro aqui, agora fala que não esperava o "." na linha 10.

$busca = $registro->xpath(‘preco[.>55.00]‘);

Troquei aspas simples, por duplas 

Agora aparece um erro na linha 14 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in /home/storage/1/c3/74/rensz1/public_html/imagemsite/testesmart/livros.php on line 14

A linha 14 é essa: echo $livro->titulo . “<br>”;

Comment: Editei a pergunta, o problema é que você copiou de algum lugar e levou junto alguns caracteres especiais, fiz algumas alterações e executei por aqui, funcionou.

Comment: Valeu @8Bit, resolveu o meu problema aqui! Muito obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu entendi, vc precisa dar uma olhada melhor no PHP, o que ocasionou todo o erro foram estas aspas duplas diferentes, foi só trocar por aspas normais e descomentar a linha do foreach como eu havia te questionado no comentário.
teste assim:

```
<?php
# Carrega e armazena o XML na variavel $xml
$xml = simplexml_load_file('estante.xml');
# laço dentro da tag livro para cada tag livro que encontrar
foreach($xml->xpath('livro') as $livro)
{
    # armazena na var $registro o conteudo de uma tag livro
    $registro = simplexml_load_string($livro->asXML());
    # executa uma consulta XPath e armazena em $busca
$busca = $registro->xpath('preco[.>55.00]');
# verificando se houve alguma busca com sucesso
    if($busca){
# exibindo os resultados encontrados
echo $livro->titulo . "<br>";
echo $livro->descricao . "<br>";
echo $livro->preco . "<br><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

estante.php

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<livros>
    <livro>
        <cod>01</cod>
        <titulo>PHP para iniciantes</titulo>
        <descricao>Desenvolvendo Aplicações web</descricao>
        <autor>Manuel da Silva</autor>
        <paginas>200</paginas>
        <preco>50.00</preco>
    </livro>
    <livro>
        <cod>02</cod>
        <titulo>XML</titulo>
        <descricao>Usando XML com PHP </descricao>
        <autor>José das Couves</autor>
        <paginas>100</paginas>
        <preco>150.00</preco>
    </livro>
    <livro>
        <cod>03</cod>
        <titulo>Javascript</titulo>
        <descricao>O Poder do javascript</descricao>
        <autor>Billy Borny</autor>
        <paginas>80</paginas>
        <preco>90.90</preco>
    </livro>
</livros>
```